# Scrollwheel ratched-mode question

Tags: mouse, games, xinput, mouse-wheel

I don't know how to describe my question in short, but bear with me.

I got a G502 Lightspeed Mouse, and ubuntu 22.04. No general problems, but i noticed that when my scrollwheel is not in free spin mode but in ratched mode, i.e. scrolling is divided in intervals with a feedback, it's kinda borked.

From a position 0, if i scroll one step up - nothing happens. If I scroll another step, it actually scrolls, and keeps scrolling every single step thereafter in the up direction. Same thing when scrolling down.

So basically I always need to scroll 2 steps in either direction to begin scrolling - which is a minor inconvenience during surfing the web - but a big one when gaming an FPS where weapon switching is bound to mousewheel up/down and i have to double scroll in the heat of the moment.

I checked xinput, and it seems like the second scroll-step triggers a button press.

here is the output:

```
motion a[3]=23295 
motion a[3]=23310 
motion a[3]=23325 
motion a[3]=23340 
motion a[3]=23355 
motion a[3]=23370 
motion a[3]=23385 
motion a[3]=23400 
button press   5 
button release 5
```

The first 7 steps (23295-23385) i scroll from position 0 one step up, then one down, then up again etc. until I double-scroll at step 8 (23400).

I tried another mouse, an MX Anywhere 3, and have the same issue.

So my questions are:
1.)  Why is that? Does it have any actual use to program it that way?
2.)  Is there any way to get each step trigger a buttonpress?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue and have narrowed down the cause to using the logid utility. When logid isn't running, scrolling is normal.

I haven't found what configuration in logid is causing this erratic scrolling, but I will continue to research and update this answer if I find anything more.